# Is it possible to redirect and mask?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm making hyper local sites that all draw on one main site using a plugin for their data.  I want to redirect links to the main site but keep the url of the hyperlocal site in the browser window..

i.e.

I want users to go to mainsite.com/place1

I want to give them a link place1.com/place1

I want the browser address bar to display place1.com/place1 (mask) but redirect to mainsite.com/place1

(they would be viewing mainsite.com/place1 but it would be masked as place1.com/place1)

how would I edit my .htaccess to do this?

Comment: Are these sites on the same server?

Comment: @user2156473 Possible only when all these sites share same `DocumentRoot` OR you enable `mod_proxy`.

Comment: how can I set up multiple domains to share the same document root?  That sounds ideal..